Create grouping of partitions in device tree and the Linux
I want to group my partitions to be able to work with the group in my C++ app.
I have a device tree with 8 partitions:
flash0: device@0 {
                ...

                part0: partition@0 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@0 (part0)

                part1: partition@1 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@1 (part1)

                part2: partition@2 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@2 (part2)

                part3: partition@3 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@3 (part3)

                part4: partition@4 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@4 (part4)

                part5: partition@5 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@5 (part5)`

                part6: partition@6 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@6 (part6)

                part7: partition@7 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@7 (part7)

                // Custom slot node linking to partitions
                group {
                    compatible = "custom,group";
                    partition0 = <&part0>; // Link to partition 0
                    partition1 = <&part1>; // Link to partition 1
                    partition2 = <&part2>; // Link to partition 2
                    partition3 = <&part3>; // Link to partition 3
                    partition4 = <&part4>; // Link to partition 4
                    partition5 = <&part5>; // Link to partition 5
                    partition6 = <&part6>; // Link to partition 6
                    partition7 = <&part7>; // Link to partition 7
                }; // end slot

            }; //end 

ls /dev/mtd*
/dev/mtd0       /dev/mtd1ro     /dev/mtd3       /dev/mtd4ro     /dev/mtd6       /dev/mtd7ro     /dev/mtdblock2  /dev/mtdblock5
/dev/mtd0ro     /dev/mtd2       /dev/mtd3ro     /dev/mtd5       /dev/mtd6ro     /dev/mtdblock0  /dev/mtdblock3  /dev/mtdblock6
/dev/mtd1       /dev/mtd2ro     /dev/mtd4       /dev/mtd5ro     /dev/mtd7       /dev/mtdblock1  /dev/mtdblock4  /dev/mtdblock7

Now, when I'm adding group node I see that in the Linux, but that directory contains files with some bin content.
00000000  00 00 00 24                                       |...$|
00000004

            flash0: device@0 {
                ...

                part0: partition@0 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@0 (part0)

                part1: partition@1 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@1 (part1)

                part2: partition@2 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@2 (part2)

                part3: partition@3 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@3 (part3)

                part4: partition@4 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@4 (part4)

                part5: partition@5 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@5 (part5)`

                part6: partition@6 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@6 (part6)

                part7: partition@7 {
                    ...
                }; //end partition@7 (part7)

                // Custom slot node linking to partitions
                groupe {
                    compatible = "custom,groupe";
                    partition0 = <&part0>; // Link to partition 0
                    partition1 = <&part1>; // Link to partition 1
                    partition2 = <&part2>; // Link to partition 2
                    partition3 = <&part3>; // Link to partition 3
                    partition4 = <&part4>; // Link to partition 4
                    partition5 = <&part5>; // Link to partition 5
                    partition6 = <&part6>; // Link to partition 6
                    partition7 = <&part7>; // Link to partition 7
                }; // end slot

            }; //end

ls -la
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Feb  7 15:52 .
drwxr-xr-x   11 root     root             0 Feb  7 15:52 ..
-r--r--r--    1 root     root            12 Feb  7 15:52 compatible
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             6 Feb  7 15:52 name
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             4 Feb  7 15:52 partition0
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             4 Feb  7 15:52 partition1
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             4 Feb  7 15:52 partition2
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             4 Feb  7 15:52 partition3
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             4 Feb  7 15:52 partition4
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             4 Feb  7 15:52 partition5
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             4 Feb  7 15:52 partition6
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             4 Feb  7 15:52 partition7

Is it possible to have links to the mtd devices?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What you are looking at is a directory in the device tree for your group node containing a bunch of properties whose values are the phandles of the partition nodes in the device tree.

What you can do is add a label string property to each partition. e.g. label = "partition0";. Then rely on the UDEV rules in "/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-mtd.rules" to create symbolic links in the "/dev/mtd/by-name/" directory, e.g. "/dev/mtd/by-name/partition0" linking to the mtd partitions with the matching labels.
